# Can I use `© 2019 My Name` in a application created by me without registering for official copyright in India?

Tags: copyright, india

[Indian gov copyright site](http://copyright.gov.in/frmfaq.aspx)

> Ques: Is it necessary to register a work to claim copyright?
>
> Ans: No.
> Acquisition of copyright is automatic and it does not require any
> formality. Copyright comes into existence as soon as a work is created
> and no formality is required to be completed for acquiring copyright.
> However, certificate of registration of copyright and the entries made
> therein serve as prima facie evidence in a court of law with reference
> to dispute relating to ownership of copyright.

Do I need any legal document to display that copyright or just that the work is created by me it is sufficient?

Comment: So what is the question, you posted the answer...?

Comment: It looks like i was confused in `(c) 2019 My Name`. Do I need any legal document to display that copyright or just that the work is created by me it is sufficient?

Comment: No, you don't need to register it to use the (C) -----, you have the copyright, in fact you don't really even need the copyright notice, the copyright is automatic and implied for most countries under the [Bern Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all [Berne Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention) countries (which includes India, the US, the UK, and almost every other country in the world) copyright is automatic, and does not need to be registered in any way. In any such country, the creator may (and is advised to) include a copyright notice such as "Copyright © YYYY by Author" (where YYYY is the year of creation, and "Author" the name under which the author claims copyright). Such a notice is not required, but may avoid any defense of "innocent" or unknowing infringement, and will be evidence of who claims copyright. Registration with any national authority is not required to obtain the basic protections of copyright, but my give additional rights or protections. For example  in the US, registration can be required to obtain statutory damages, and for works by US nationals, is required before any infringement suit is filed. I don't know what benefits it gives in India.